# Sudoku solving taking forever to run

Tags: python, backtracking, sudoku

The example below is working however, if more zeros (empty cells) are added to the sudoku grid `g`, it takes longer to run, if it ever finishes. Not asking for a code review here, just I might've overlooked something, and I'd appreciate pointing it out.

```
def is_solved(grid):
    for row, col in zip(grid, [*zip(*grid)]):
        for i in range(1, 10):
            if (i not in row) or (i not in col):
                return False
    return True


def square_available(rows, x, y, n):
    if 0 <= x < 3:
        rows = rows[:3]
    elif 3 <= x < 6:
        rows = rows[3:6]
    else:
        rows = rows[6:]
    if 0 <= y < 3:
        return not any([n in r[:3] for r in rows])
    elif 3 <= y < 6:
        return not any([n in r[3:6] for r in rows])
    else:
        return not any([n in r[6:] for r in rows])


def is_valid(grid, x, y, n):
    columns = [*zip(*grid)]
    return (
        square_available(grid, x, y, n) and n not in grid[x] and (n not in columns[y])
    )


def solve(grid, empty_cells):
    if is_solved(grid):
        return grid
    for x, y in empty_cells:
        for n in range(1, 10):
            if is_valid(grid, x, y, n):
                grid[x][y] = n
                empty_cells.remove((x, y))
                if solve(grid, empty_cells):
                    return grid
                else:
                    grid[x][y] = 0
                    empty_cells.append((x, y))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    solution = [
        [5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2],
        [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8],
        [1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7],
        [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3],
        [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
        [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
        [9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4],
        [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
        [3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9],
    ]
    g = [
        [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 8, 9, 1, 0],
        [6, 0, 2, 0, 9, 0, 3, 4, 0],
        [1, 9, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7],
        [0, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 3],
        [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
        [7, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0, 8, 0, 0],
        [9, 6, 0, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 0],
        [2, 0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0],
        [3, 4, 0, 2, 8, 0, 1, 7, 9],
    ]
    empty = []
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if not g[i][j]:
                empty.append((i, j))
    solved = solve(g, empty)
    assert g == solution
```

I tried reimplementing the whole thing as shown below, and the results got worse. It's not even capable of solving what's already possible with the implementation above.

```
from collections import defaultdict


def get_possibilities(rows, columns, x, y, visited):
    if (x, y) in visited:
        return visited[x, y]
    x0 = (x // 3) * 3
    x1 = x0 + 3
    y0 = (y // 3) * 3
    y1 = y0 + 3
    possibilities = set()
    for n in range(1, 10):
        square_rows = rows[x0:x1]
        for row in square_rows:
            if n in row[y0:y1]:
                continue
        if (n not in rows[x]) and (n not in columns[y]):
            visited[x, y].add(n)
            possibilities.add(n)
    return possibilities


def solve(rows, columns, empty_cells, visited):
    if not empty_cells:
        return rows
    for x, y in empty_cells:
        for n in get_possibilities(rows, columns, x, y, visited):
            rows[x][y] = n
            columns[y][x] = n
            visited[x, y].remove(n)
            if solve(rows, columns, empty_cells - {(x, y)}, visited):
                return rows
            else:
                rows[x][y] = 0
                columns[y][x] = 0
                visited[x, y].add(n)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    solution = [
        [5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2],
        [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8],
        [1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7],
        [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3],
        [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
        [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
        [9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4],
        [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
        [3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9],
    ]
    r = [
        [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 8, 9, 1, 0],
        [6, 0, 2, 0, 9, 0, 3, 4, 0],
        [1, 9, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7],
        [0, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 3],
        [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
        [7, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0, 8, 0, 0],
        [9, 6, 0, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 0],
        [2, 0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0],
        [3, 4, 0, 2, 8, 0, 1, 7, 9],
    ]
    c = [list(r) for r in [*zip(*r)]]
    cells = set()
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if not r[i][j]:
                cells.add((i, j))
    v = defaultdict(set)
    solved = solve(r, c, cells, v)
    assert r == solution
```

Comment: Why test with 0 at all? 1 to 9 need testing…

Comment: what do I need to change?

Comment: You make many copies of the grid in `is_valid` and `square_available`. Try to remove all the slicing and zipping, and your code should be a lot faster. Next, you're calling `is_valid` for each n=1..9. Instead, `is_valid` could return the numbers that are valid in a particular square, which can be done efficiently by accumulating all the numbers that are already in the row/column/square.

Comment: On a more algorithmic note, you're trying empty squares in the order they appear on the grid. It's vastly (exponentially) more efficient to try the empty square with the fewest possibilities in first, because this will find impossible choices much faster.

Comment: @PaulHankin I don't think it just needs some optimization, I tried reimplementing the whole thing without `is_valid` and without zipping, and the results got worse. I edited the question and added the new changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking only at the first version of your code, there are a few things you can improve in the `solve` function:

- (A problem also in the second version:) You shouldn't *loop* over all `empty_cells`. Instead consider that you **must** find a solution for the first empty cell, and if after doing all of the recursive effort there is no good value for this first empty cell, then it makes no sense to continue with other empty cells. The first one represents a problem that is unsolvable, so any effort on any other empty cell is useless. So remove that `for` loop, and just work with **one** empty cell per recursion level.
- You don't need to call `is_solved` to know that the grid has been completed. You did this better in the second version. Just test `not empty_cells` or something similar.
- Don't call `empty_cells.remove` and `append` in each iteration of the inner loop as it is always the same that is removed and added again. Moreover, `remove` is overkill as you don't really want to *search* for the entry -- you know at which index it sits. Just do the removal at the start of the process, and add it again at the very end.

With the above changes the performance will greatly improve. Still some little improvements are possible:

- Leave the `empty_cells` list unmutated, and instead pass along an index in that list. We can assume that all empty cells before that index have been filled in, and the others are still to do.
- Instead of calling `is_valid` on each digit, collect the valid moves -- an idea you tried to implement in the second version.

Here is the improved version:

```
def valid_moves(grid, x, y):
    ybox = y - y % 3
    xbox = x - x % 3
    return set(range(1, 10)).difference(
            grid[x]
        ).difference( 
            (row[y] for row in grid)
        ).difference(
            (num for row in grid[xbox: xbox + 3]
                for num in row[ybox: ybox + 3])
        )

def solve(grid, empty_cells, i=0):
    if i >= len(empty_cells):  
        return grid
    x, y = empty_cells[i]
    i += 1
    for n in valid_moves(grid, x, y):
        grid[x][y] = n
        if solve(grid, empty_cells, i):
            return grid
        grid[x][y] = 0
```